# Connect to a network share with different credentials

Tags: powershell

I have a .pptx file on a network share, where user 1 doesn't have access to.
Now I want to open this file with different credentials from a domain user who has access to.
How can i achieve that?

This is what I have

```
$cred = Get-Credential
New-PSDrive -Name "z" -Root "\\server1\folder1" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Persist:$true -credential $cred -ea SilentlyContinue
start "\\server1\folder1\News-Ticker.pptx" 
Remove-PSDrive -name "z"
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: there is no error. problemn is the networt share isnt mapped. the network share exist for 100%

Comment: You have parameter `-ea SilentlyContinue` so you don't know if you have an error. Replace with `-ea Stop` or `-ea Continue` to get error message.

Comment: Have you seen the note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.1#example-4--create-a-persistent-mapped-network-drive-using-credentials) _"Remember, if you use the above snippet in a script, set the Scope parameter value to "Global" to ensure the drive persists outside the current scope."_

Comment: @Theo has that, but I question how you're going to remove the drive in the last line if the file remains open?

Comment: I can't connect to the share because of it says double connections are not allowed. I am definitely connected twice. Is it possible just to start the pptx file on the share with other credentials? When i try that it says username or password are incorrect but this isnt true